# Matlab ask for integer loop

Tags: matlab, random, prompt

I'm creating a program to simulate a random walk and it requires the user to input an integer number of steps to take for the walk.

The prompt for this uses code very similar to this:

```
    **% Ask user for a number.
    defaultValue = 45;
    titleBar = 'Enter a value';
    userPrompt = 'Enter the integer';
    caUserInput = inputdlg(userPrompt, titleBar, 1,{num2str(defaultValue)});
    if isempty(caUserInput),return,end; % Bail out if they clicked Cancel.
    % Round to nearest integer in case they entered a floating point number.
    integerValue = round(str2double(cell2mat(caUserInput)));
    % Check for a valid integer.
    if isnan(integerValue)
    % They didn't enter a number.  
    % They clicked Cancel, or entered a character, symbols, or something else not allowed.
    integerValue = defaultValue;
    message = sprintf('I said it had to be an integer.\nI will use %d and continue.', integerValue);
    uiwait(warndlg(message));
    end**
```

However, I want it to simply display the "Enter a value" prompt again if the user does not enter an integer the first time i.e. 4.4.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
if (mod(integerValue,1) == 0)
```

will evaluate to true if integerValue is an integer. Simply augment your if statement w/ this logic. You might want to consider changing to using a while loop so the user can enter bad input more than once.

Answer (score 1):

The first answer is totally correct for checking for an integer value, but to address the "show prompt again" issue you can just use a loop conditioning it to get the exact kind of data you want:

```
caUserInput = nan; %or anything worng for that matter
while isempty(caUserInput) || isnan(caUserInput)
    caUserInput = inputdlg(userPrompt, titleBar, 1,{num2str(defaultValue)});
end
```

if you want you can start it again with different argument lines in a more fancy style:

```
inputiswrong = 1; %or anything worng for that matter
while inputiswrong 
    inputiswrong = 0;
    caUserInput = inputdlg(userPrompt, titleBar, 1,{num2str(defaultValue)});
   if isempty(caUserInput )
      userPrompt = 'Try again with an input';
      inputiswrong = 1;
   end
   if isnan(caUserInput )
      userPrompt = 'not really a number';
      inputiswrong = 1;
   end
   %and so on
end
```

In both scenarios you should consider transforming the caUserInput to something you could use, i think inputdlg returns a cell so maybe a cell2mat() around the inputdlg().

Answer (score 1):

Remember that unspecified inputs in MATLAB are double-precision by default. For instance `a=3` is not an integer. So you should consider two cases:

---

#### Integer type

If you are talking about integer type in MATLAB the easiest way is to use `isinteger` function by MATLAB:

```
tf = isinteger(A)
```

for instance:

```
isinteger(4.4)
=
    0
```

as I mentioned before, 3 is not an integer:

```
isinteger(3)
=
    0
```

but this one is integer actually:

```
isinteger(uint8(3))
=
    1
```

To repeat the input query also easily use the same function in a while loop

```
while ~isinteger(a)
    disp('enter an integer');
    ....
end
```

---

### Constant double-precision with no decimal

But if you are considering normal constant inputs to be integers you could convert them to integer and compare the result with the original value:

```
while a ~= double(int64(a))
    disp('enter an integer');
    ....
end
```

`int64` converts the double type to integer, and `double` converts it back to double. If in this process the number remains unchanged, then you could consider that it was intended to be an integer.

---

#### Recommendation for you specific program

I would use a `fix` function to get rid of the decimal parts. Usually when you receive a double-precision number including decimal values, the main intention is the the number before the floating point. So in many algorithms it is common practice to use `fix` to round each element of the given number to the nearest integer toward zero.